# Bitbucket: relation team project repository

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am using git after to see the differences between TFS and GIT. we choosed Bitbucket but I am not clear if it is possible to do the next thing:

Make a team for each repository and each repository relationed with ONE project only. Is it possible?

If not, what is the  meaning of project in Bitbucket?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

The high level is project (like Team Project on TFS), you can create a one repository or more on each project (the repo is relationed only to the project in which it was created). 
You can create a team for each repository.

**Useful links:**

[Creating projects](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/creating-projects-776639848.html)

[Creating repositories](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/creating-repositories-776639815.html)

[Create and grant access to team repositories](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/create-and-grant-access-to-team-repositories-665225545.html)

By the way, you can use GIT on TFS.

Comment: Can you share two teams in the same project?

Comment: @David In TFS  you can create multiple teams within the same project, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/scale/multiple-teams?view=vsts

Comment: Not interested in TFS, in Bitbucket please and Git